# Somar valores de subquerys separadamente

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou com um problema nessa query abaixo:

```
select
  sum(tb1.l1) * 0.3,
  sum(tb2.l2) * 0.3
from
  (
    select
      setor,
      total_geral as l1
    from
      mobile.auditoria
    where
      month(data) = month(now())
      and year(data) = year(now())
      and setor regexp '[1]' = 1
    group by
      setor
    order by
      data
  ) as tb1,
  (
    select
      setor,
      total_geral as l2
    from
      mobile.auditoria
    where
      month(data) = month(now())
      and year(data) = year(now())
      and setor regexp '[2]' = 1
    group by
      setor
    order by
      data
  ) as tb2;
```

quando faço assim:

```
select
  sum(tb1.l1) * 0.3,
  sum(tb2.l2) * 0.3
from
  (
    select
      setor,
      total_geral as l1
    from
      mobile.auditoria
    where
      month(data) = month(now())
      and year(data) = year(now())
      and setor regexp '[1]' = 1
    group by
      setor
    order by
      data
  ) as tb1;
```

me traz o valor certo da soma dos totais vezes 0.3, porém ao acrescentar a segunda subquery, `tb2`, o valor vem acumulado.

Alguém sabe por que está dando esse problema? Gostaria de trazer os valores sem acumular, como é feito quando eu faço em uma subquery só.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente colocar o `SUM` dentro de cada um dos `SUBSELECT` ao invés de os utilizar na consulta principal:

```
select  tb1.l1 * 0.3
    ,   tb2.l2 * 0.3  
from    (
            select      setor
                    ,   sum(total_geral) as l1  
            from        mobile.auditoria 
            where       month(data)         = month(now())  
                    and year(data)          = year(now()) 
                    and setor regexp '[1]'  = 1 
            group by    setor 
        ) as tb1,
        (
            select      setor
                    ,   sum(total_geral) as l2  
            from        mobile.auditoria 
            where       month(data)         = month(now()) 
                    and year(data)          = year(now()) 
                    and setor regexp '[2]'  = 1 
            group by    setor 
        ) as tb2
```